# ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-ios/Lottie.modulemap' not found when testing with detox

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, e2e-testing, detox

I recently updated my project to react-native 0.61.5 but now my e2e are failing for ios. The project is not able to build due to Lottie.
I had the same problem building the project in my machine but was able to solve it by opening xcworkspace instead of xcodeproj, but when I try to do the same with detox config I get the error

**error: 'ios/Project.xcworkspace' is not a project file.**

My detox config:

```
"detox": {
    "configurations": {
      "ios.sim.debug": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Project.app",
        "build": "xcodebuild -UseModernBuildSystem=NO -project ios/Project.xcodeproj -scheme Project -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone 11"
      },
      "ios.sim.release": {
        "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/Project.app",
        "build": "xcodebuild -UseModernBuildSystem=NO -project ios/Project.xcodeproj -scheme Project -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
        "type": "ios.simulator",
        "name": "iPhone 11"
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Any solution for this ?